# Sprite cut in half after placed on Scene

Tags: sprites, unity

I have noticed a very odd behaviour in Unity 5.2.1. When I drag and drop a Sprite into the Scene, it's cut in half like this:

[image]

I tried with PNG and PSD formats but it didn't help. Although when I flipped an image horizontaly in PS and then imported it, it worked. Is this a Unity bug?

**Edit:** It happens only when I set Max Size to 512 or more, but still - why?

Comment: What shader are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a clipping plane problem in the scene view when you have large sprites that should not cause problems in your game view. Select the sprite and press F to focus on that object in the scene view. This will adjust clipping planes to suit the object's size. Any difference?

As far as I know you can not adjust the Scene View clipping but your game view clipping is adjusted on your active camera.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html